# Como totalizar os dias de acordo com um período?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select

Como totalizar os dias de acordo com um período?

Exemplo:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------+----------+
| data_ini     | data_fim     | codfun | qtd_dias |
+--------------+--------------+--------+----------+
| '2014-01-15' | '2014-01-31' | 1      | 16       |
| '2014-02-01' | '2014-02-28' | 1      | 27       |
| '2014-03-01' | '2014-03-22' | 1      | 21       |
| '2014-03-10' | '2014-03-31' | 2      | 21       |
| '2014-04-01' | '2014-04-30' | 2      | 29       |
| '2014-05-01' | '2014-05-12' | 2      | 11       |
| '2014-04-08' | '2014-04-30' | 3      | 22       |
| '2014-05-01' | '2014-05-31' | 3      | 30       |
| '2014-05-01' | '2014-06-19' | 3      | 49       |
+--------------+--------------+--------+----------+
```

Preciso totalizar a coluna `qtd_dias` por `codfun` e trazer o período inicial e final (data mais antiga em `data_ini` e data mais recente em `data_fim`), por exemplo:

```
+--------+--------------+--------------+----------------+
| codfun | data_ini     | data_fim     | qtd_dias_total |
+--------+--------------+--------------+----------------+
| 1      | '2014-01-15' | '2014-03-22' | 66             |
| 2      | '2014-03-10' | '2014-05-12' | 63             |
| 3      | '2014-04-08' | '2014-06-19' | 72             |
+--------+--------------+--------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Amigo @mcardoso, dava pra dar mais alguma informação sobre a lógica de agrupamento, ou algum preâmbulo(sito)? Eu não percebi muito bem.

Comment: A primeira tabela está idêntica como está no banco de dados e a segunda (que é o resultado), seria a ramificação da primeira, ou seja, deve-se colocar a data de início e fim mês a mês, de acordo com o período da primeira tabela, resultado na nesta segunda.

Comment: Suas somas nos dados representativos estão errados, seria intencional? A solução do @luigibertaco funciona corretamente no MySQL.

Comment: A Reestruturação da pergunta feita pelos adm do stackoverflow está errada! é o contrário mesmo! preciso do detalhamento e não do agrupamento.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que no seu caso seria algo do tipo:

```
select codfun, min(data_ini), max(data_fim), sum(qtd_dias) from TABELA group by codfun;
```

não tenho certeza de como isto vai se comportar no mysql, mas acredito que não tenha diferença com outros bancos.